# Need Help Setting up TS/CC's on XPR8300 Talk Groups

Tags: repeater, dmr, motorola

New Motorola XPR8300 repeater in place, but NO idea how to set up Talk Groups. HELP!

Tommy NH7R

Comment: Hello Tommy, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: This is a [question-and-answer site](https://ham.stackexchange.com/tour) rather than a forum-style discussion site, and so we favor questions that are as complete as possible.  This helps other people in the future who will have the same problem and will find your question in a web search.  Please consider expanding your question.  Are you having trouble with the concept of talk groups?  Are you unfamiliar with the setup tools?  That's the kind of information we're looking for.